# Set-builder defining set size and valid elements? Notation help.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm working on some documentation for a system that uses an arbitrary waveform generator that accepts data with a number of requirements. I would like to include some formal definitions of the requirements for academic readers, as well as an exercise for myself.

The device requires a set of between 128 and 8 million elements (inclusive), the number of elements must also be a multiple of 8. Each element in the set must be an even integer between -32768 and 32766 (inclusive).

I've put together what I think is correct(ish?), but I'm not sure if I'm mixing and matching conventions because I've looked at many different sources for reference. I was unable to find an example of a set-builder definition that both described the restrictions on the size of the set as well as the elements within the set.

This is what I have:

$$
S = \{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},...,v_{n} : \exists a \in \mathbb{Z} s.t. n=8a\wedge128\le n \le 8000000\wedge\forall v \in S( \exists b \in \mathbb{Z} s.t. v=2b\wedge-32768\le v \le 32766)\}
$$

First off, is this correct? Secondly, is this an advisable way to define this set via set-builder notation?

To be clear, the documentation will also contain a "plain english" definition of the set, similar to my second paragraph. Having a formally notated definition of this set isn't a strict requirement, but I'd like to know with certainty for my own benefit how to express this formally if it were.

Comment: (1) Writing in "formal notation" does not impress the "academic reader". What does impress the academic reader is crystal clarity in the language used to define everything. (2) Since there are not even $2^{16}$ numbers in the range given, I suspect that you meant a multiset, or even an array, rather than a set. Is that correct?

Comment: 1) I apologize if I failed to stress that impressing anyone isn't important. The question was generated in the course of this task, but the desire for an answer is primarily for personal interest.
2) Yes, elements can appear more than once. I see that this does mean it isn't a set. Thanks for asking that question. I'll revise my question after lunch.

Comment: One big problem I see is the self-reference to the set $S$ $(\forall v \in S)$ in the very definition of $S$. It's circular.

Comment: Asaf Karagila, over lunch I decided that your insight showed that my question was intrinsically flawed to the point that I'd be better off to close it, and learn what I need to learn about multisets and arrays.

I'm new to this site, so I'm not sure what the proper etiquette is in this case. I think your comment actually qualifies as a best answer, so if you want to post it in a way that I can select it as a best answer I will.